# how to add inbound rule using group policy

Tags: windows, windows-firewall, group-policy, netsh

We can add inbound rules using : Netsh advfirewall firewall cmd
But,I need to add inbound rule in Local Group Policy -under Windows FireWall using cmd or script.

Please let me know your input.

Comment: You need to provide more details here to get answers.  Supply some code sample, error messages, or other details to improve your chance of getting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run netsh to set rules to Local Group Policy in an single liner code, but  You can use the scripting option with `netsh -f <script file>`

The script file should contain the cmds that is required for adding the Local Group Policy.

as a sample script.txt

```
advfirewall
set store gpo=%COMPUTERNAME%
```

After the above lines, you can add your firewall rules.

You can pass this script.txt to `netsh -f script.txt`

> Make sure that this cmd is run in an elevated console.